# Can't iterate through excel or .csv with pandas or openpyxl

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I'm trying to iterate through a column of a pandas dataframe from .csv with pandas, and I've tried .xlsx with openpyxl, and copy to a new dataframe if the string contains substring "Leading Edge". I'm getting the error "TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable" even though the columns and rows should be integers.
I've tried printing out sample values and it works fine, so I'm not sure why it isnt working with either a for lop with int i as iterator, nor .iter_rows iterator (openpyxl).
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Using openpyxl

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook

path = r"C:\Users\austi\Downloads\IVY 19 Clock Genes"

workbook = load_workbook(path + "\\newSheetfromJupyter.xlsx", read_only=True)
readSheet = workbook.active

wb = Workbook()
newSheet = wb.active
df = pd.DataFrame
for row in readSheet.iter_rows(min_row = 2,
                               min_col = 1,
                               max_col = 18,
                           values_only = True):
    if("Leading Edge" in row[1]):  #ERROR CORRESPONDS TO HERE
        df.append((cell.value for cell in row[0:18]))
print(df)
```

Using pandas

```
LE = dfWithCol.groupby(dfWithCol.tumor_region)
for i in range(len(dfWithCol.index)):
    if("Leading Edge" in dfWithCol.tumor_region[i]): #ERROR HERE
        LEf = LE.get_group(dfWithCol.tumor_region[i])
print(LEf)
```

Comment: You don't need `cell.value` because you already have `values_only=True`

Comment: embed a sample csv in your question (in raw CSV text format, not in dataframe format). and also give a sample dataframe output with the expection you want. Also, my recommendation is to use pandas and CSV, not excel and openpyxl

Comment: What's the error message?

Answer (score 0):

You can't iterate an int, you can only iterate sequence types (such as **list**, **str**, and **tuple**) and some non-sequence types (like **dict**, **file objects**, and objects of any classes you define with an **iter**() method or with a **getitem**() method).
I just added a str() to your code and it worked on my device.

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook

workbook = load_workbook("test.xlsx")
readSheet = workbook.active

wb = Workbook()
newSheet = wb.active
df = pd.DataFrame
for row in readSheet.iter_rows(min_row = 2,
                               min_col = 1,
                               max_col = 18,
                           values_only = True):
    if("Leading Edge" in **str(row[1])**):  #ERROR CORRESPONDS TO HERE
        df.append((cell.value for cell in row[0:18]))
print(df)
```